# Is there a python tip to filter icons from a string?

Tags: python, regex, string

```
items = ['Bana is goog for health \n☑ \n#50',
         'it is what \nwhat \n-Timing \n☑ \n#51 \nAlignment',
         'Interval Snapshots - Timing Alignment \n☑ \n#49',
         'Nous vous remercions - Reso \n☑ \n#53']
```

Is there any regular expression solution to filter each item from the ☑ symbole and #number, so the result have to be something like this:

```
items = ['Bana is goog for health',
         'it is what \nwhat \n-Timing \nAlignment',
         'Interval Snapshots - Timing Alignment',
         'Nous vous remercions - Reso']
```

Answer (score 0):

With the third-party `regex` module:

```py
import regex

def sanitize(string):
  return regex.sub(r'\s*(?:\p{So}|#\d+)', '', string).rstrip()
```

...in which `\p{So}` means all Unicode symbols that are not math symbols, currency signs or combining characters and `#\d+` means a `#` followed by one or more digits. `\s*` will matches any whitespaces character before either one of those. The `\p{}` syntax is not supported by the built-in `re`, but `regex`.

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/5diL3b/1) (PCRE2).

Try it:

```py
testcases = [
  'Bana is goog for health \n☑ \n#50',
  'it is what \nwhat \n-Timing \n☑ \n#51 \nAlignment',
  'Interval Snapshots - Timing Alignment \n☑ \n#49',
  'Nous vous remercions - Reso \n☑ \n#53'
]

print([sanitize(testcase) for testcase in testcases])

'''
[
  'Bana is goog for health',
  'it is what \nwhat \n-Timing \nAlignment',
  'Interval Snapshots - Timing Alignment',
  'Nous vous remercions - Reso'
]
'''
```

Alternatively, just specify the exact symbol you want to remove in a `re`-compatible manner:

```py
r'\s*(?:☑|#\d+)'
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/5diL3b/2).